# Which model is most appropriate to represent this sample data?

Tags: self-study, model-selection

I need to determine the most appropriate model to represent the data. It should not be determined from only the $R^2$ value but also from the shape, and need to explain why.

[image]

What makes one graph better than another? Like, does the negative number on the quartic and quintic models make it less appropriate?
And on the sextic model, some of the numbers are very small and must have been significantly rounded by Excel. So does any of this make it less appropriate?

Answer (score 5):

Basically, you are concerned about overfitting. There are several model comparison frameworks that all ultimately compare whether the additional explanatory power of a new parameter is justified by how much additional variance it explains. Information criteria (such as AIC & BIC) are a common and relatively simple framework you could investigate.

But more generally, I would consider what your goal is here. Are you specifically trying to explain a pattern? Do you need a parameteric version of this equation or are you just trying to illustrate a trend and possibly interpolate? If the latter, I would investigate GAMs (generalized additive models), which are flexible and their common implementations automatically identify the appropriate level of complexity (/wiggliness) for the data.